# Laravel Relationships over 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i have a Laravel relationship Problem. I have 4 tables with columns...

**tbl_applicants**

`applicant_id(key)`

**tbl_link_applicant_contact_history**

- `link_id(key)`
- `applicant_id`
- `contact_history_id`

**tbl_contact_history**

- `id(key)`

**attachments**

- `id(key)`
- `contact_history_id(foreign_key from tbl_contact history)`
- `filename`

```php
class Applicant extends Model
{
    public function attachments() 
    {
      ...relationship
    }
}
```

How can I build relationship with Eloquent to get attachments in Applicant model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the relationships

```
Applicant<---many-to-many--->ContactHistory<---one-to-one/one-to-many--->Attachment
```

I am assuming one-to-one between `ContactHistory` and `Attachment` for simplicity and you can build up from there. Then you can model your models like:

**EDIT**

You can use the `hasManyThrough` in the **Applicant** Model in to retrieve many **Attachments** through **ContactHistory** Model. The **Applicant** Model code is updated with the method. More information in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

**Applicant Model**

```
class Applicant extends Model
{
    /**
     * The contacthistories that belong to the applicant.
     */

    public function contacthistories() 
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(ContactHistory::class);
    }


   /**
    * Get all of the attachments for the applicant.
   */
   public function attachments()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(ContactHistory::class, Attachment::class);
   }

}
```

**ContactHistory Model**

```
class ContactHistory extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the attachment for the contact history.
     */
    public function attachment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Attachment::class);
    }
}
```

So now for an `Applicant` you can get all the associated `Attachments` by

```
$applicant = Applicant::find(1);

// Loop through all the contacthistories of an applicant, where each contacthistory $ch has an attachment.

foreach ($applicant->contacthistories as $ch) {
        $ch->attachment;
}
```

**Note**: I have not shown here the `Attachment` model which is also simply a model class where you can have inverse relationship to the `ContactHistory` model. Hope this gives you enough to get started.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.I use lumen with json api and i have a generic method for get requests, By request of an applicant , all given relationships are with  included. 

Applicant::with($includes);

Can I build a direct relationship drom applicant to attachments?

Comment: I have updated the answer to have the possibility with `hasManyThrough`.

Comment: perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: @outlaw you can accept the answer if it helped you :)